# Shape drawn using SVG Path is not proper

Tags: javascript, svg

I have drawn a shape using svg path. The shape is nothing but the rectangle drawn as below. The lines are blurred and it is not clear. Please find the code snippet and screen shot below.

```
<path fill="#D13F41" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" d="M 107 457 L 107 457 L 456 491 L 434 498 L 79 462 ">
```

[image: Shape]

Is there any property i need to set for the path element to render properly without any blur in the shape.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The blur you are seeing is anti-aliasing, there is really no way to get rid of it entirely but there are a couple of things you can try to reduce it:

- Try to offset your lines by `0.5px` so they don't fall exactly on a pixel boundary. You can either do a translation by `0.5 0.5`, or add the offset to your path (i.e. start at 107.5). Sometimes this can help.
- Set your stroke width to to `1.5` instead of `1`
- In your css, set `shape-rendering: crispEdges;`  This tells the browser not to do any anti-aliasing at all.  Works great for horizontal and vertical lines, but will probably make diagonal lines look horrible.

Comment: All of the points of your path are integers, try to offset them by 0.5 like this: `d="M 107.5 457.5 L 107.5 457.5 L 456.5 491.5 L 434.5 498.5 L 79.5 462.5 "`